# JFrame doesn't responds at all

Tags: java, jframe

I made a voice call application using java. the frame consists of two buttons one is to call and another is to cut the call. My problem is whenever i press the call button the threads starts running and the data(voice) is transmitted continuously but the other operations such as the cut button or frame close button doesn't respond at all. it is as if the frame hangs. can someone help me out with this?

Edit: this is my client code. haven't made any frames for server. it just runs on another machine.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Program extends JFrame implements ActionListener
  {
 JButton jbtOpen, c;
 JFrame f1=new JFrame();
 JPanel PPanel1;
 JLabel limg=new JLabel();
public final static String SERVER = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter server IP");
public Program()
{
    PPanel1 = new JPanel(null);
    PPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1366,786));
    Container con=getContentPane();
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("voicecall.jpg");
    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("voicecall1.jpg");
    ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon("call.jpg");
    jbtOpen=new JButton("Call");
    c=new JButton("Cut");
    limg.setIcon(image1);
    jbtOpen.setIcon(image2);
    c.setIcon(image3);
    limg.setBounds(0,0,1500,700);
    jbtOpen.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
    c.setBounds(200,50,100,100);
    PPanel1.add(limg);
    PPanel1.add(jbtOpen);
    PPanel1.add(c);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Voice Calling");
    con.add(PPanel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    jbtOpen.addActionListener(this);
    c.addActionListener(this);
            f1.addWindowListener(new W1());
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == jbtOpen)
                {
                   try {
                    open();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                    if(e.getSource() == c){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

   }
public void open() throws Exception
 {
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(8000.0f,8,1,true,false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, af);
TargetDataLine microphone = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
microphone.open(af);
Socket conn = new Socket(SERVER,3000);
microphone.start();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] soundData = new byte[1];
Thread inThread = new Thread(new SoundReceiver(conn));
inThread.start();
while(bytesRead != -1)
{
    bytesRead = microphone.read(soundData, 0, soundData.length);
    if(bytesRead >= 0)
    {
        dos.write(soundData, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
System.out.println("IT IS DONE.");
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
       Program b=new Program();
}
  private class W1 extends WindowAdapter
{
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
    System.exit(0);
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: My guess is that you haven't *actually* launched a new thread at all, but are tying up the UI thread. We can't check that without seeing code though.

Comment: We need to see some code. How are you stopping that thread you started with the call button? If you're just using standard Thread or Runnable, you need to call interrupt() and then provide some way of recognizing interruption inside the thread and return from the run() method. It could be more complicated, as in if you're using I/O and it's blocking, then in your loop where you transmit data, you'll need to interrupt that. Basically, we can't diagnose the problem without a minimal example that runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with code.

Comment: Per the above commenters, you're doing the work in the UI Thread. See SwingWorker class, and put everything in your "open" method in a SwingWorker.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a few problems with this code. The `actionPerformed` method will NEVER reach System.exit() because you have this code block:

```
if(e.getSource() == c){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

*inside* the `if(e.getSource() == jbtOpen)` code block. You need an else in there at the very least.

System.exit() isn't a great way to clean up a running thread. You should shut it down more gracefully with at least an interrupt() or something.

Comment: yah i understand what you u r speaking bt the frame just hangs after i press the call button. the buttons are like fixed. like the frame is dead.

Comment: You've got a tight loop in there reading a byte at a time from a blocking IO call. UI will never be refreshed as long as there is data coming down the pipe. All of that crap in the open() method should be put in a SwingWorker thread as @user1676075 suggested yesterday.